# How to insert data into another table from a variable in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I would like to insert the data from a variable (which is a table name) into another table inside a stored procedure. But when I try altering the stored proc I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

**SQL:**

```
INSERT INTO DBNAME..Table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM @Tablevariable;
```

**Error:**

> Must declare the table variable "@Tablevariable".

`@Tablevariable` is already declared in my stored procedure.

Comment: The variable which I declared consists a table name. I would like to insert data into another table from this variable.

Comment: Post the entire contents of the stored procedure.

Comment: You are going to have to show us your code in order for us to help you.  There is a bug in your code.  We cannot tell you what it is unless you show us your code.

Comment: Without this piece of insert the stored proc is working fine...

Comment: I cant post the entire code here....

Comment: Wild guess: you've misspelled @tablevariable, either here or in the declaration.

Comment: I found the solution folks.... have to use exec sp_executesql to run my command....

Comment: Wild guess (it's not clear from the problem statement), but you're trying to put a name of a table into a variable, and use that... you can't. You have to use Dynamic SQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of doing `FROM @TableVariable`. I think instead you'd need to do either:

1. Stick a case statement in there so if `@TableVariable = 'Customers'` select from customers table.  The problem with is though every time you create a new table you must update your stored proc.
2. Build out the text as a string within SQL: `DECLARE sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select blah blah blah FROM ' + @TableVariable` (or something like that).  Then call `exec(sqlCommand)`. The problem with this is though, you wont' get query optimization on the sqlCommand.

Comment: `FROM @tablevairable` works just fine in SQL Server.  That;s not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the table-name be a variable.  You could do something like this in the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Tablevariable nvarchar(50) = 'MyTableName'
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO DBNAME..Table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM ' + @Tablevariable

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```